# Re-arranging an array to have keys have values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a Javascript array of objects as below

```
const lab = [
  {
    name: "Lance",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "117.69",
    "4-Aug-21": "120.1",
    "5-Aug-21": "122.08",
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "100.14",
    "4-Aug-21": "101.2",
    "5-Aug-21": "103",
  },
  {
    name: "Vince",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "12.65",
    "4-Aug-21": "13.29",
    "5-Aug-21": "13.68",
  },
];
```

I have this modified as below

```
const labCheck = [
  {
    id: "Lance",
    values: [
      { date: "3-Aug-21", risklevel: "117.69" },
      { date: "4-Aug-21", risklevel: "120.1" },
      { date: "5-Aug-21", risklevel: "122.08" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "Sam",
    values: [
      { date: "3-Aug-21", risklevel: "100.14" },
      { date: "4-Aug-21", risklevel: "101.2" },
      { date: "5-Aug-21", risklevel: "103" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "Vince",
    values: [
      { date: "3-Aug-21", risklevel: "12.65" },
      { date: "4-Aug-21", risklevel: "13.29" },
      { date: "5-Aug-21", risklevel: "13.68" },
    ],
  },
];
```

I have tried the code below

```
const labCheck = lab
  .map((d) => d.name)
  .map(function (name) {
    // console.log(id);
    return {
      id: name,
      values: Object.keys(lab[0])
        .slice(2)
        .map(function (d, id) {
          return {
            date: d,
            risklevel: +lab[id][d],
          };
        }),
    };
  });
```

It seems to work, I get the structure but the values of `riskLevel` are the same for all the `id`'s and that is incorrect.

[image]

I have tried to correct this for a couple of days now but no luck.
Can any one please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to isolate and rename the properties we're interested in at each level of refactoring.

```js
const lab = [{ name: "Lance", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "117.69", "4-Aug-21": "120.1", "5-Aug-21": "122.08", }, { name: "Sam", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "100.14", "4-Aug-21": "101.2", "5-Aug-21": "103", }, { name: "Vince", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "12.65", "4-Aug-21": "13.29", "5-Aug-21": "13.68", },];

const labCheck = lab.map(({ name: id, item, ...values }) => ({
  id,
  values: Object.entries(values).map(([date, risklevel]) => ({ date, risklevel }))
}));

console.log(labCheck)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you need to mutate values as part of the refactoring you can't use the [property shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) but will need to explicitly declare each property and assign the relevant mutated value.

```js
const lab = [{ name: "Lance", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "117.69", "4-Aug-21": "120.1", "5-Aug-21": "122.08", }, { name: "Sam", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "100.14", "4-Aug-21": "101.2", "5-Aug-21": "103", }, { name: "Vince", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "12.65", "4-Aug-21": "13.29", "5-Aug-21": "13.68", },];

const labCheck = lab.map(({ name: id, item, ...values }) => ({
  id,
  values: Object.entries(values).map(([date, risklevel]) => ({ 
    date: new Date(Date.parse(date)), // Date.parse() is not reliable, but used as example here.
    risklevel: +risklevel 
  }))
}));

console.log(labCheck)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Javascript community is so cool. I got 5 answers within 10mins! Thank you. I will he accepting Nick's answer since he was first (I am new to JS & I do not know to evaluate the code on other parameters). Up-Voting your answer as well.

Comment: no worries, though the use of `slice()` in that answer is fragile as the key order is not guaranteed. Also do explore destructuring assignment as it can be a powerful and descriptive tool.

Comment: will definitely check it out.

Comment: Nice destructuring

Comment: @pilchard How can I make risk level as number instead of string ( I also want to parse the date in with d3.dateParse) your code? When I try to add unary plus, i am getting error.

Comment: To parse the values in the returned object you can't use the property shorthand, you'll need to use standard object syntax, so: `{ date: new Date(date), risklevel: +risklevel }`. (answer edited to reflect this)

Comment: @pilchard Thanks for the update & clarification. Due to my limited JS knowledge, I could not determine that your's was the best answer. However, based on UpVotes & comments, yours is apparently the beast answer. Accepted it as the answer. Can you suggest a site where i can learn about 'destructuring assignment' & other array methods? I have looked at MDN but i am not able to understand it. Coming from Python, JS syntax seems a bit different, hence still looking for a site.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
Object.keys(lab[0])
```

You ALWAYS take the first element of the array, instead of iteration over themn.

Also, you concatenate two `.map` method. When you do that, the second map will receive as input the output of the previous method, in your case the name, thus losing access to the original element.

You can use:

```js
const lab=[{name:"Lance",item:"PS","3-Aug-21":"117.69","4-Aug-21":"120.1","5-Aug-21":"122.08"},{name:"Sam",item:"PS","3-Aug-21":"100.14","4-Aug-21":"101.2","5-Aug-21":"103"},{name:"Vince",item:"PS","3-Aug-21":"12.65","4-Aug-21":"13.29","5-Aug-21":"13.68"}];


const labCheck = lab.map((item) => {
  return {
    id: item.name,
    values: Object.keys(item)
      // The order of the keys is not guaranteed, better not to use .slice() because it could fail on unpredicatable situations
      .filter((key) => key !== 'name' && key !== 'item')
      .map((key) => {
        return { date: key, riskLevel: item[key] }
      })
  }
})

console.log(labCheck)
```

Comment: Best answer imo, should be the accepted one

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```js
const lab = [
  {
    name: "Lance",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "117.69",
    "4-Aug-21": "120.1",
    "5-Aug-21": "122.08",
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "100.14",
    "4-Aug-21": "101.2",
    "5-Aug-21": "103",
  },
  {
    name: "Vince",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "12.65",
    "4-Aug-21": "13.29",
    "5-Aug-21": "13.68",
  },
];

const formattedLab = lab.map((el) => {
  const values = Object.entries(el).slice(2);
  return {
    id: el.name,
    values: values.map(value => ({
      date: value[0],
      riskLevel: +value[1]
    })),
  }
});

console.log(formattedLab);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been breaking my head over this for 2 days now!

Comment: Note the casting to float using the unary plus. Perhaps you need them as string?

Comment: I need it actually the risk level as numbers, so unary plus is perfect. That is a plus for this answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to access the data in the array and return it.

```js
const lab=[{name:"Lance",item:"PS","3-Aug-21":"117.69","4-Aug-21":"120.1","5-Aug-21":"122.08"},{name:"Sam",item:"PS","3-Aug-21":"100.14","4-Aug-21":"101.2","5-Aug-21":"103"},{name:"Vince",item:"PS","3-Aug-21":"12.65","4-Aug-21":"13.29","5-Aug-21":"13.68"}];

// `map` over the array
const out = lab.map(obj => {

  // Grab the name, and item, and then everything else
  const { name, item, ...rest } = obj;

  // `map` over the object entries and for each iteration
  // return a new object
  const values = Object.entries(rest).map(([key, value]) => {
    return { date: key, riskLevel: value };
  });

  // Return the new array
  return { name, values };

});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Javascript community is so cool. I got 5 answers within 10mins! Thank you. I will he accepting Nick's answer since he was first (I am new to JS & I do not know to evaluate the code on other parameters). Up-Voting your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```js
const labCheck = lab.map((obj, i) => {
    const newObj = {id: obj.name, values: []};
    Object.keys(lab[i]).slice(2).forEach(date => {
        newObj.values.push({
            date: date, 
            risklevel: lab[i][date]
        });
    })
    return newObj;
})
```