# Using an external object in array map() method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array of objects as below

```
const history = [
  {
    name: "Lance",
    baseline: { risk: "112", age: "45" },
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    baseline: { risk: "9", age: "21" },
  },
];
```

Then a second one as below

```
const current = [
  {
    name: "Lance",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "117", 
    "4-Aug-21": "120", 
    "5-Aug-21": "112",
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "10.14",
    "4-Aug-21": "10.2",
    "5-Aug-21": "10",
  },
];
```

Can anyone help getting the output as below

```
const currentRiskRating = [
  {
    name: "Lance",
    values: [
      { date: "3-Aug-21", riskLevel: "104.4" }, //117/112(112 is the baseline risk for Lance)
      { date: "4-Aug-21", riskLevel: "107.1" }, //120/112(112 is the baseline risk for Lance) 
      { date: "5-Aug-21", riskLevel: "100" }, //112/112(112 is the baseline risk for Lance)
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    values: [
      { date: "3-Aug-21", riskLevel: "112.6" }, //10.14/9(9 is the baseline risk for Sam)
      { date: "4-Aug-21", riskLevel: "113.3" }, //10.2/9(9 is the baseline risk for Sam)
      { date: "5-Aug-21", riskLevel: "111.1" }, //10/9(9 is the baseline risk for Sam)
    ],
  },
];
```

I got my question yesterday where the value in the array of objects are rearranged. Link -->
[Re-arranging an array to have keys have values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862874/re-arranging-an-array-to-have-keys-have-values)

The difference in this question is that here I am trying to read the `risk` from the `history` array and divide the values for the dates (I have added the comment where I show how the values is arrived at). Essentially we find the `risk` in the `baseline` and then divide the values for each date with the value. Please let me know how I can accomplish this.
I am unable to pass an external array into map() method.

Comment: And the problem is? Just add the calculcation of `riskLevel` into the answer of your linked question.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: But how to pass-in the `history` into the map() method which is on the `current` array? in the map() method of one array, can I pass-in the values from another array? I do not know the risk of each person, it has to be searched from the `history` array based on the name of the person.

Comment: The second parameter the `.map()` callback is an index. Assuming the indexes match you can use `.map((item, index) => ... history[index].baseline.risk ... )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the optional chaining in case there is no item matching the history

```js
const current = [
{ name: "Lance", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "117",   "4-Aug-21": "120",  "5-Aug-21": "112", },
{ name: "Sam",   item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "10.14", "4-Aug-21": "10.2", "5-Aug-21": "10",  },
];

const history = [ 
{ name: "Lance", baseline: { risk: "112", age: "45" }, },
{ name: "Sam",   baseline: { risk: "9", age: "21"   }, },
];

const labCheck = current.map(({ name: id, item, ...values }) => {
  const baseline = history.filter(item => item.name===id)[0]?.baseline.risk ?? 1
  console.log(baseline)
  return {
  id,
  values: Object.entries(values).map(([date, risklevel]) => ({ date, risklevel: parseInt((+risklevel/+baseline)*100) }))
}
});

console.log(labCheck)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. In my expected output I converted the `+risklevel / +baseline` into percentage, hence the issue in you results. However, the method you provided is perfect. I changes to  `+risklevel / +baseline` to `(+risklevel / +baseline) * 100` and it works fine for me (I get the result I was expecting). TIL, that we can indeed pass another array into the map() method.

Answer (score 1):

You could first build a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) that maps each `name` from `history` to its `risk`:

```
Lance -> 112
Sam -> 9
```

Once you have the Map, you can get the persons risk by using `.get()` on the current `name`, and perforrm your calculation with that risk:

```js
const history = [ { name: "Lance", baseline: { risk: "112", age: "45" }, }, { name: "Sam", baseline: { risk: "9", age: "21" }, }, ];

const current = [ { name: "Lance", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "117", "4-Aug-21": "120", "5-Aug-21": "112", }, { name: "Sam", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "10.14", "4-Aug-21": "10.2", "5-Aug-21": "10", }, ];

const historyMap = new Map(history.map(o => [o.name, o.baseline.risk]));
const res = current.map(({name, item, ...rest}) => ({
  name,
  values: Object.entries(rest).map(([date, risk]) => ({
    date,
    riskLevel: ''+Math.floor((risk / historyMap.get(name)) * 1000) / 10
  }))
}));

console.log(res);
```