# Create array of objects based by filtering the data based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array of objects as below

```
const history = [
  {
    name: "Lance",
    baseline: { risk: "112", age: "45", insurance: "Star" },
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    baseline: { risk: "9", age: "21", insurance: "Sigma" },
  },
  {
    name: "Jill",
    baseline: { risk: "15", age: "21", insurance: "Sigma" },
  },
  {
    name: "Bill",
    baseline: { risk: "15", age: "21", insurance: "Mercy" },
  },
];
```

Then a second one as below

```
const current = [
  {
    name: "Lance",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "117",
    "4-Aug-21": "120",
    "5-Aug-21": "112",
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "10.14",
    "4-Aug-21": "10.2",
    "5-Aug-21": "10",
  },

  {
    name: "Jill",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "10.14",
    "4-Aug-21": "10.2",
    "5-Aug-21": "10",
  },
  {
    name: "Bill",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "10.14",
    "4-Aug-21": "10.2",
    "5-Aug-21": "10",
  },
];
```

Can anyone get the output as below.

```
const filteredData= [
{
  insurance: 'Star',
  details:
  {
    name: "Lance",
    values: [
      { date: "3-Aug-21", riskLevel: "104.4" }, //117/112(112 is the baseline risk for Lance)
      { date: "4-Aug-21", riskLevel: "107.1" }, //120/112(112 is the baseline risk for Lance)
      { date: "5-Aug-21", riskLevel: "100" }, //112/112(112 is the baseline risk for Lance)
    ]
  }},
  {insurance: 'Sigma'
  ,
  details:
  {
    name: "Sam",
    values: [
      { date: "3-Aug-21", riskLevel: "112.6" }, //10.14/9(9 is the baseline risk for Sam)
      { date: "4-Aug-21", riskLevel: "113.3" }, //10.2/9(9 is the baseline risk for Sam)
      { date: "5-Aug-21", riskLevel: "111.1" }, //10/9(9 is the baseline risk for Sam)
    ],
name: "Jill",
    values: [
      { date: "3-Aug-21", riskLevel: "112.6" }, //10.14/9(9 is the baseline risk for Sam)
      { date: "4-Aug-21", riskLevel: "113.3" }, //10.2/9(9 is the baseline risk for Sam)
      { date: "5-Aug-21", riskLevel: "111.1" }, //10/9(9 is the baseline risk for Sam)
    ],
  },
},
{insurance: 'Mercy',
details:
  {
    name: "Bill",
    values: [
      { date: "3-Aug-21", riskLevel: "104.4" }, //117/112(112 is the baseline risk for Lance)
      { date: "4-Aug-21", riskLevel: "107.1" }, //120/112(112 is the baseline risk for Lance)
      { date: "5-Aug-21", riskLevel: "100" }, //112/112(112 is the baseline risk for Lance)
    ],
  }
},
];
```

I got a similar questions answered. Link --> [Using an external object in array map() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68873125/using-an-external-object-in-array-map-method?noredirect=1#comment121719116_68873125)

The difference in this question is that here I am trying to read the insurance from the history array and then get the values for patients of the same insurance together.

Based on the previous question.
I have the Map between name & insurance with the code below.

```
const historyMap = new Map(history.map(o => [o.name, o.baseline.insurance]));
```

However, I do not know how to use it further.

I got the code below where they categorize stuff based on the 'coins' (in our case insurance & data is also structured differenly) but I am not able to figure it out.

```
filteredData = {};
  Object.keys(data).forEach((coin) => {
    filteredData[coin] = data[coin]
      .filter((d) => {
        return !(d["price_usd"] == null);
      })
      .map((d) => {
        d["price_usd"] = Number(d["price_usd"]);
        d["24h_vol"] = Number(d["24h_vol"]);
        d["market_cap"] = Number(d["market_cap"]);
        d["date"] = parseTime(d["date"]);
        return d;
      });
  });
```

Comment: In my opinion  `details` in `filteredData` should be array.

Comment: If the 'details' is an array, it cannot have `name:<value>` key/value pair inside it.

Comment: It will array of object. Using the current format will overwrite the previous value.

Comment: @moys You mentioned that you are new to JS. But you approved an answer which uses `Array.reduce`, `Array.map`, `Object destructuring` and n number of advanced JavaScript techinques and not a single line explanation provided for the logic that he used. And the best thing is the user stated to Other answes that Assuming the nodes other than name and item in current array as date is not possible since that wont work with dynamic data. The approved answer also uses of the same technique. So what is the reason for the accepting that particular answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a two loops approach with objects as hash tables.

```js
const
    history = [{ name: "Lance", baseline: { risk: "112", age: "45", insurance: "Star" } }, { name: "Sam", baseline: { risk: "9", age: "21", insurance: "Sigma" } }, { name: "Jill", baseline: { risk: "15", age: "21", insurance: "Sigma" } }, { name: "Bill", baseline: { risk: "15", age: "21", insurance: "Mercy" } }],
    current = [{ name: "Lance", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "117", "4-Aug-21": "120", "5-Aug-21": "112" }, { name: "Sam", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "10.14", "4-Aug-21": "10.2", "5-Aug-21": "10" }, { name: "Jill", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "10.14", "4-Aug-21": "10.2", "5-Aug-21": "10" }, { name: "Bill", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "10.14", "4-Aug-21": "10.2", "5-Aug-21": "10" }],
    temp = current.reduce((r, { name, item, ...data }) => {
        r[name] = Object
            .entries(data)
            .map(([date, riskLevel]) => ({ date, riskLevel }));
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = Object.values(history.reduce((r, { name, baseline: { risk, insurance } }) => {
        r[insurance] ??= { insurance, details: [] };
        r[insurance].details.push({
            name,
            values: temp[name].map(({ date, riskLevel }) =>
                ({ date, riskLevel: (100 * riskLevel / risk).toFixed(1) }))
        });
        return r;
    }, {}));
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I used `reduce()` to categorize the insurance and extract the data with `Object.values()`.

note: the precision I didn't know your requirement. I leave for you to adjust. I use toFixed(1) now.

```js
const history = [ { name: "Lance", baseline: { risk: "112", age: "45", insurance: "Star" }, }, { name: "Sam", baseline: { risk: "9", age: "21", insurance: "Sigma" }, }, { name: "Jill", baseline: { risk: "15", age: "21", insurance: "Sigma" }, }, { name: "Bill", baseline: { risk: "15", age: "21", insurance: "Mercy" }, }, ]; 

const current = [ { name: "Lance", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "117", "4-Aug-21": "120", "5-Aug-21": "112", }, { name: "Sam", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "10.14", "4-Aug-21": "10.2", "5-Aug-21": "10", }, { name: "Jill", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "10.14", "4-Aug-21": "10.2", "5-Aug-21": "10", }, { name: "Bill", item: "PS", "3-Aug-21": "10.14", "4-Aug-21": "10.2", "5-Aug-21": "10", }, ];

const categorizedInsurance = history.reduce((acc, h) => {
  const cur = current.find(c => c.name === h.name);
  const insurance = h.baseline.insurance;
  const keys = Object.keys(cur).filter(key => key !== "name" && key !== "item");
  const values = keys.map(key => ({
    date: key,
    riskLevel: ((cur[key] / h.baseline.risk) * 100).toFixed(1),
  }));

  if (acc[insurance]) {
    acc[insurance].details.push({
      name: h.name,
      values: values,
    });
  } else {
    acc[insurance] = {
      insurance: insurance,
      details: [
        {
          name: h.name,
          values: values,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

const output = Object.values(categorizedInsurance);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: it works on the data in the question. I will try to run this on my actual data. Thanks. Up-Voted.

Comment: in your output `details` appears twice for insurance 'Sigma'. It should appear only once since we are trying to categorize all other data based on 'insurance'

Comment: @moys, do you want the details to be a array of object then?

Comment: yes. I think I missed the square brackets there. We have to first map name with insurance & for each insurance, an array of the name plus the relevance data.

Comment: In this code also, it seems that the assumption is made that "For each nodes inside the current array, loop through the keys. The keys other than name and item are supposed to be dates." This is an assumption it works as of now, but if the data changes, this can change & the code may not work. The code gives the result as expected, may not be future proof.

Comment: @moys, `if the data changes, this can change & the code may not work.` Yes. it is true and what you need to do is actually change the `current` array structure if possible. Such as like `{
    name: "Sam",
    item: "PS",
    date: [
      { "3-Aug-21": "10.14" },
      { "4-Aug-21": "10.2" },
      { "5-Aug-21": "10" },
    ],
  },` This way, you can get date easily from a object.

Comment: OK. I will try. I am new to JS, I do not know how to do it but I will take is as an assignment for left & do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Checked with the syntax of the `filteredData`. But it seems that the `details` node in each object of `filteredData` array must be an array, since there are multiple nodes with key as name.

**Logic**

- Loop through the `current` array.
- For the each object in `current` array find a matching node from `history` array having same name.
- For each nodes inside the `current` array, loop through the keys. The keys other than `name` and `item` are supposed to be dates.
- Create a `detail` object with `name` as the matching name from history array and an empty `values` list.
- Generate the values for each date with calculation for `risk`.
- Push this details to the `accumulator` array.
- Before pushing verify whether a node already exist with same insurance name in the `accumulator` array. If there is already a node exist, the newly created detail object is to be pushed to the details array of that node, or else push a new node to the `accumulator` array.

**Working Example**

```js
const history = [
  {
    name: "Lance",
    baseline: { risk: "112", age: "45", insurance: "Star" },
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    baseline: { risk: "9", age: "21", insurance: "Sigma" },
  },
  {
    name: "Jill",
    baseline: { risk: "15", age: "21", insurance: "Sigma" },
  },
  {
    name: "Bill",
    baseline: { risk: "15", age: "21", insurance: "Mercy" },
  },
];
const current = [
  {
    name: "Lance",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "117",
    "4-Aug-21": "120",
    "5-Aug-21": "112",
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "10.14",
    "4-Aug-21": "10.2",
    "5-Aug-21": "10",
  },

  {
    name: "Jill",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "10.14",
    "4-Aug-21": "10.2",
    "5-Aug-21": "10",
  },
  {
    name: "Bill",
    item: "PS",
    "3-Aug-21": "10.14",
    "4-Aug-21": "10.2",
    "5-Aug-21": "10",
  },
];

const output = current.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // Find the node from the array `history` having the same name from array `current`
  const historyNode = history.find(node => node.name === curr.name);
  const details = [];
  const detail = {
    name: historyNode.name,
    values: [],
  }
  // Loop through each keys in the object `curr`
  // If the node is not `name` and `item` then defenitely its a date
  Object.keys(curr).forEach((key) => {
    if (key !== 'name' && key !== 'item') {
      // Push the date values against the name
      detail.values.push({
        date: key,
        risk: (+curr[key] / +historyNode.baseline.risk * 100).toFixed(1)
      })
    }
  })
  details.push(detail)

  // Find for a node an insurance same as that we found match from the history array.
  // If there is a match found, then this details must be pushed to the `details` array of that particular node
  const accumulatorNode = acc.find((node) => node.insurance === historyNode.baseline.insurance);
  if (accumulatorNode) {
    accumulatorNode.details.push(detail);
  } else {
    // If there is no node existing with same insurance name, then we need to insert a new object to the accumulator
    acc.push({
      insurance: historyNode.baseline.insurance,
      details,
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(output)
```

Comment: "For each nodes inside the current array, loop through the keys. The keys other than name and item are supposed to be dates." This is an assumption it works as of now, but if the data changes, this can change & the code may not work. The code gives the result as expected, may not be future proof. Up-voted.

Comment: @moys your aprved answer also uses this assumption. Update the nodes inside the `current` array and see the code breakes beautifully. See this fiddle to see how the code works with an updated data https://jsfiddle.net/0wvf5du2/

Comment: @moys then what is the criteria to identify the dates?